# How to auto load page/div using jquery ajax to the data within foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, database

Till now I am stuck with these code here the code for ajax I know This is wrong ..or something is not right ..

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 

      setInterval(function() {

         $('#divToRefresh').load('userCount.php', function(data) {

            $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
                  alert(value);
            });
           });
          }, 3000);
        });
      </script>
```

here the userCount.php

```
$get_temp = "SELECT * FROM temperature_setting WHERE device_key = 'YMR200'";
    $result = $conn->query($get_temp);

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          $temp_id[] = $row['temp_id'];

      }
      foreach ($temp_id as $id_value) {
         $get_current_value = "SELECT $id_value FROM data_current WHERE device_key = 'YMR200'";
            $result_value = $conn->query($get_current_value);
              $row_value = $result_value->fetch_assoc();
                  $value[] = $row_value[$id_value];
     }
        print_r($value);
```

there are 15 value so each value  should go to each

```
 foreach ($temp_id as $id_value) { ?>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>
<?php } ?>
```

according currently the out put of userCount is

```
Array ( [0] => 65 [1] => -8 [2] => -5 [3] => -3 [4] => -5 [5] => 25 [6] => -5 [7] => -5 [8] => -5 [9] => -5 [10] => -5 [11] => -5 [12] => -5 [13] => 25 [14] => -5 )
```

what I want is to put these value in each

```
    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh"></p>
    <br>
```

Comment: You've repeated the same `id` attribute throughout the DOM. That's invalid as they must be unique. Use a `class` instead

Comment: what will be the change ...even if I make the class it is inside loop so still will be the same

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You're looping through the 15 divs, making an AJAX request for each, then attempting to stuf the same looped values from your PHP in to every div? Making one AJAX request would make much more sense

Comment: What I am trying to do is... I have that div inside a loop that will give 15 div of same id..now I want to fetch the value from ajax load where I have return the 15 value .. to each div respectively..

Comment: Can you add expected output how you want exactly

Comment: <p id="divToRefresh">65</p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh">-8</p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh">-5</p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh">-3</p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh">5</p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh">25</p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh">-5</p>
    <br>

    <p id="divToRefresh">-5</p>
    <br> ..and so on respectively

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is what you want

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'userCount.php',
            cache: false
          }).done(function(data) {
            $.each($(data), function(key, value) {
              $('#itemsTableBody').append($('<tr>').append($('<td>').text(value)));
            });
          });
        }, 3000);
      });
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="itemsTableBody"></tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>Item</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```